# Screen flashes gray as I log in, can I stop it?

Tags: 11.10, login, unity-2d, nvidia-optimus, hybrid-graphics

Since installing 11.10 I've noticed that often when I login the following sequence:

- login screen [hit enter]
- light gray screen (0.5 - 1 sec)
- my background appears
- Unity loads
- Guake loads

I'm running on a fairly beefy i7 so I don't think it's a lack of hardware, unless its that the Intel card can't cope but the NVidia would. (I'm running one of those hybrid graphics machines.)

Is there any way to stop this flash from happening? Can I change the color? Is it a bug?

Comment: It started happening to me as well, but only after I installed gnome-shell. And I have an ATI card. Weird.

Comment: The gray screen is simply indicating that you are (automatically) being downgraded to Unity-2D.  So your issue is: **Why is my graphics setup not supporting Unity (3D)?**

Comment: Are you using Unity-2D? Unity 2D has this problem already reported:  <I can’t find the bug right now>

Comment: @david6 you're right, for some reason I had this account set to unity2d

Comment: @fitoschido thanks for confirming that, I couldn't find it either but I've noted it in my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known Metacity bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/metacity/+bug/864779) visible when logging in to a Unity 2D session.

Switch to Unity 3D, or wait for the bug to be resolved.

Comment: one bug on https://bugs.launchpad.net/metacity/+bug/864779

Comment: Presumably this is ONLY _cosmetic_, and does not otherwise effect used of **Unity-2D**?

Comment: @david6 clarified wording

Comment: yes, just a 'cosmetic' issue